# convert prices with exchangerates from other table SUM and get AVG

Tags: sql, mariadb

What my idea is:

Server: Ubuntu with latest MariaDB

It's a portfolio algo, the user can buy stocks in a currency like USD but his portfolio can be in EURO, so the values must be converted.

1. I need a exchange rate near the created date, if not use a rate from date before.
2. SUM the amounts_lefts * price converted to currency i want (in this case for easier understand it will be a rate of 1, the target currency will submit over query in this case 2.
3. the result should be divides though the sum of amounts_left to get the correct buyIN aka AVG price.

Ive updated the data to make things more simple for test, like currency of source is now the same as target, so the calculation is 1:1

```
SQL Fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c7fc59/11
Results running against my DB with querys 

    https://pastebin.com/pSerHN0j
```

the first 2 results are what i want, the 3. one is from jmvcollaborator where the AVG BuyIN is correct but the amounts are doubled

```
SQL Export with more Data 

    https://pastebin.com/d1aVX2wm
```

Updated Question:

The solution over Subquery is working, but this Method is not the best in performance, so im currently looking for a solution without this.

After my Information partitions over should be here a solution, but this is not my kind of knowledge, so maybe anyone can help me here.

Comment: much better if you can add tables and data here, http://sqlfiddle.com/ then share the Url :)

Comment: @jmvcollaborator they dont let me create :(

Comment: why your table and column names have that weird apostrophe ? can i edit your question and remove them ?

Comment: @ jmvcollaborato sure u can, ive did only a sql export over phpmyadmin

Comment: Edit your question please add input and desired Output detailing each calculation made. by the way, the data you have provided is not related, transaction table has currency_id in NULL

Comment: @jmvcollaborator no its 1, null is import ID. i have added the other infos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253866/discussion-between-jmvcollaborator-and-stefanbd).

Comment: "....we got a solution which is currently working", and now the question remains: What is the question left to be answered?

Comment: @Luuk i cant close it or mark it as solved

Comment: @Luuk please leave it opened, we need to update the code in the question, thanks !

Comment: @StefanBD unless im freaking out this query (your first one) works ? SELECT SUM(amounts_left*price)/SUM(amounts_left) as eBuyIN
 FROM transactions as t 
 WHERE 1 GROUP BY currency_id,broker_id,portfolio_id,instrument_id;

Comment: hi @StefanBD since you are ensuring a 1:1 relationship between the two tables does the first approach (the one without joining exchange) still works for you ? IMHO i would not take it valid

Comment: Adding to above comment that query is not considering any date.

Comment: which one? this on line 4?  sure this is the "master query" who dont need currency calculation  because we go from euro to euro and the 2. and 3. should have exact this results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write some findings here, first i would like to double check that your very first query works, please confirm:

```
SELECT SUM(amounts_left*price)/SUM(amounts_left) as eBuyIN
 FROM transactions as t 
 WHERE 1 GROUP BY currency_id,broker_id,portfolio_id,instrument_id;
```

If it does not work then let me share some findings with regards of the query we got working which is:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(price)/SUM(mleft) 
FROM(
    SELECT
        `instrument_id`,
        amounts_left AS mleft, 
        amounts_left * price * (
             SELECT `rate` 
             FROM `currency_exchanges` 
             WHERE `from_currency_id` = t.currency_id 
               AND `to_currency_id` = 2 
               AND `date` <= t.created 
             ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1
        ) AS price
    FROM `transactions` AS `t` 
    WHERE `action` = 1 
      AND `portfolio_id` = 128 
) a
```

The query cost is 2.72 since it perform a full table scan due the nested query. I took the freedom to try a different approach using CTE and OVER PARTITION BY and the query cost is 0.35 a non unique key look up due the columns inside the partition thus much faster that the previous query, here is the CTE code:

```
WITH 
cte AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.currency_id,t.broker_id,t.portfolio_id,t.instrument_id ORDER BY amounts_left DESC
        ) AS rowNumber,        
       SUM(amounts_left) OVER(PARTITION BY t.currency_id,t.broker_id,t.portfolio_id,t.instrument_id
       ORDER BY amounts_left DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS amountsleftT,       
       SUM(amounts_left*price) OVER(PARTITION BY t.currency_id,t.broker_id,t.portfolio_id,t.instrument_id
       ORDER BY amounts_left DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS priceT
FROM currency_exchanges AS ce
JOIN transactions AS t
ON from_currency_id = t.currency_id 
AND to_currency_id = 2 
AND ce.date <= t.created
AND action = 1 and portfolio_id = 128 
)
Select priceT/amountsleftT as Total from cte where rowNumber = 1;
```

I would suggest to add more data so many different cases can be tested you can keep working on the fiddle and share the link.

Hopefully i have helped somehow.

**UPDATE** query with Over Partition By was updated cause the aggregates were wrong. **IMPORTANT**: still the performance is better than the other approaches.
Here is the working query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
select 
instrument_id,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.currency_id,t.broker_id,t.portfolio_id,t.instrument_id) AS rowNumber,
Sum(amounts_left* price *ce.rate) OVER(PARTITION BY t.currency_id,t.broker_id,t.portfolio_id,t.instrument_id) AS priceSum,
Sum(amounts_left) OVER(PARTITION BY t.currency_id,t.broker_id,t.portfolio_id,t.instrument_id) amountsleftSum 
from transactions t left join
     (select ce.*, row_number() over (partition by from_currency_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from currency_exchanges ce
      where
         to_currency_id = 2     
      order by ce.date desc
     ) ce
     on ce.from_currency_id = t.currency_id and seqnum = 1
  WHERE 
    ce.date <= t.created 
    AND action = 1 AND amounts_left > 0 AND portfolio_id = 128 
    
)    
SELECT     
 priceSum/amountsleftSum as   eBuyIN,
       amountsleftSum AS amounts_left,
       instrument_id       
 FROM cte
 WHERE  rownumber = 1;
```

Comment: i have added/changed more data here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c7fc59/11 and replace the exchange rate to 1 (or better say the trans currency is now target currency) for better checking. I can confirm that the 1 and 2. Query (had add some fields) results in the same buyIN price even number 3 got the correct price the problem on 3 is that the amount left is doubled.  Ive run this against my DB, sqldiddle showed me null on some prices dunno why.  I have paste my results and sqls here https://pastebin.com/pSerHN0j  i have exported the 2 tables from my db here https://pastebin.com/d1aVX2wm

Comment: btw. why do you do a order by ORDER BY amounts_left ?

Comment: With regards to the order by please refer to https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-partition-by-clause-overview/ and check the Section ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING

Comment: with regards to the structure and data change I recommend to Update the question (including working fiddle links)

Comment: thanks, question have been updated, i will see when i got the time for sqlshack

Comment: mind to add a few test cases? input and expected output

Comment: i think its clear, I've describe everything in the  pastebin links, will add the info about 3. case from you which is wrong

Comment: see the update on the answer, i tested with your provided structures/data. and now approach #3 (with over partition by) returns the same as the first two approaches

Comment: Thanks its working, speed on my version vs your depends on the amount of entrys in currency_exchanges, with current we have 0.004 Sec vs 0.001 Sec. Need only testing a little more, i had strange results in tests after emptying the currency_exchanges and add a 1:1 its was working so its maybe a problem with my data. Also need check why in the old case your query was missing data and now i have all